# Should 150 000 tiny rocks be set as static in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, static

I have 2500 x 2500 units size terrain in my game and on the surface of the terrain is 150 000 tiny rocks without colliders, physics, shadows or anything. They never move they just sit there. Would I benefit anything from setting these rocks `static` or is there something else I could do to make performance but keep the rocks. I've already set the culling distance of the rocks to 125. I'm printing FPS to UI text to check performance on mobile also. On mobile my fps is 60 with or without the rocks but on PC I get 40 FPS without the rocks and 30 FPS with the rocks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes as Unity would batch them together to lower the batch count.

Answer (score 4):

As a minimum you should make sure that your objects qualify for [batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html).

[Static](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html) is one way that can help you achieve this. But I'm guessing you haven't placed the 150 000 objects manually in the editor, so you won't benefit from the editor optimizations static gives.

However you can put the objects under a parent and call [StaticBatchingUtility.Combine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StaticBatchingUtility.Combine.html). You call this only once, after all 150 000 objects has been placed.

Taking it a step further I you can try to put multiple rocks into one object, for example by [combining meshes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html). Then reuse one or more of these objects to qualify for batching and achieve higher FPS. Each object can contain multiple tiny rocks and you can layer them a bit randomly to achieve a random look. Note that there is limit of 65536 vertices on meshes so it may not be enough with a single object to get the random look you want.

The main gist of it is that you want to avoid separate draw calls for each object. Check [rendering statistics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingStatistics.html) for improvements as you optimize. Also note that there is some CPU and memory overhead of having that many objects, this can be avoided by using larger objects to contain multiple smaller meshes.